# List of Character Encodings

Tags: character-encoding

Is There A Book or Site That Teaches And Also Includes A Complete List of Character Encoding's That Includes Hexadecimal, Decimal and Name Versions?

If you can name a couple of books and sites, that would be very helpful thank you.

Answer (score 12):

http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what character set you want.  For the ASCII characters, `man ascii` will do it on most Unix systems.  For all of Unicode, there's an [enormous standard](http://www.unicode.org/standard/standard.html).  For HTML entities, there's the [W3C](http://www.w3c.org/).  Perhaps you could be more specific about what characters you are interested in?

Answer (score 1):

1. [Latin alphabet 1: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-1)
2. [UTF-8: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/)
3. [Unicode code charts: http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode5.1.0/](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode5.1.0/)

There are many more online resources available and Wikipedia has links to most useful ones.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many character encodings that there is no one exhaustive source.

You should look at:

- [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/)
- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding)

Between them, they are likely to be close to exhaustive.